# Parsing JSON on Event Hub messages using spark streaming

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, azure-eventhub

I am trying to parse a `JSON` file streaming through `EventHub`, I am converting the body of the message to `string` and then I am using `from_json`, as shown below. I am able to save the entire `JSON` object as a single cell in a delta table (which happens when I writestream out of df4 in the below code), however when I use `body.*` or `col(body.*)` to split the `json` into multiple columns I get an error. Any suggestions on how to handle this.

```
// Scala Code //
val incomingStream = spark.readStream.format("eventhubs").options(customEventhubParameters.toMap).load()

incomingStream.printSchema()

val outputStream = incomingStream.select($"body".cast(StringType)).alias("body")
                                
val df = outputStream.toDF()
val df4=df.select(from_json(col("body"),jsonSchema))
val df5=df4.select("body.*")

df5.writeStream
  .format("delta")
  .outputMode("append")
  .option("ignoreChanges", "true")
  .option("checkpointLocation", "/mnt/abc/checkpoints/samplestream")
  .start("/mnt/abc/samplestream")
```

Output

```
root
 |-- body: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- partition: string (nullable = true)
 |-- offset: string (nullable = true)
 |-- sequenceNumber: long (nullable = true)
 |-- enqueuedTime: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- publisher: string (nullable = true)
 |-- partitionKey: string (nullable = true)
 |-- properties: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)
 |-- systemProperties: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: string (valueContainsNull = true)

root
 |-- body: string (nullable = true)

AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'body.*' given input columns 'body'
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.UnresolvedStarBase.expand(unresolved.scala:416)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$.$anonfun$expand$1(Analyzer.scala:2507)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$.withPosition(package.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$.org$apache$spark$sql$catalyst$analysis$Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$expand(Analyzer.scala:2506)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$.$anonfun$buildExpandedProjectList$1(Analyzer.scala:2526)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:242)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$.buildExpandedProjectList(Analyzer.scala:2524)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$18.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:2238)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$apply$18.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:2233)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$3(AnalysisHelper.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.CurrentOrigin$.withOrigin(TreeNode.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.$anonfun$resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning$1(AnalysisHelper.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper$.allowInvokingTransformsInAnalyzer(AnalysisHelper.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.AnalysisHelper.resolveOperatorsUpWithPruning(AnalysisHelper.scala:133)
```

The below link shows the way to display on console and it works for me, I am trying to write the json to a delta file with multiple columns.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57298849/parsing-event-hub-messages-using-spark-streaming]

Comment: What error are you receiving? Please update the question with the error and associated stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code seems to be how you have used `alias` and as a result the column `body` is no longer available. A few observations with what you have aliased in your code and what you may try to resolve this issue:

**Observation 1**

*Issue:*

```scala
val outputStream = incomingStream.select($"body".cast(StringType)).alias("body")
```

Your code above is aliases the entire dataframe. If your intention is to ensure the `body` column is aliased as `body` after the string cast, you may try the following

*Suggestion:*

```scala
val outputStream = incomingStream.select($"body".cast(StringType).alias("body"))
```

**Observation 2**

Where you have

*Issue:*

```scala
val df4=df.select(from_json(col("body"),jsonSchema))
```

You should use an alias so that you may access it later as it is now referenced by another name (you may use `printSchema` and `show` to see this for yourself while debugging).

*Suggestion:*

```scala
val df4=df.select(from_json(col("body"),jsonSchema).alias("body"))
```

Comment: @NgD Great! Please upvote this answer then mark as the accepted answer for this question to help other stackoverflow users who experience similar issues to easily identify answers that worked for the question that may solve their issue.